# why this multi column subquery not working in MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery

```sql
SELECT ENAME, HIREDATE, SAL 
FROM emp
WHERE (YEAR(HIREDATE), SAL) IN (
  SELECT YEAR(HIREDATE), MAX(SAL)
  FROM emp
  GROUP BY YEAR(HIREDATE)
);
```

error message

> : SELECT ENAME, HIREDATE, SAL  FROM emp WHERE (YEAR(HIREDATE), SAL) IN
> (   SELECT YEAR(HIREDATE), MAX(SAL)   FROM emp   GROUP BY
> YEAR(HIREDATE) ) LIMIT 0, 1000    Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of
> HAVING clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
> column 'scott.emp.HIREDATE' which is not functionally dependent on
> columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
> sql_mode=only_full_group_by   0.000 sec

```sql
-- ok

SELECT YEAR(HIREDATE), MAX(SAL)
FROM emp
GROUP BY YEAR(HIREDATE)
```

| yea(hiredate) | max(sal) |
| --- | --- |
| 1980 | 800 |
| 1981 | 5000 |
| 1987 | 3000 |
| 1982 | 1300 |

Comment: If you are are looking for an explanation of functional dependency and how mysql implements it start here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: But I guess you are wondering why running the sub query on it's own produces correct result? I suspect this is a bug and you should rewrite as a join. https://dbfiddle.uk/7cpJ7U7g

Comment: [Error related to only_full_group_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34115174/3404097)